# How to name 3 equal but separate teams?

Tags: team

We're trying to come up with naming schemes for a team that is splitting up into 3 equal but separate teams working off the same backlog. To most outsiders, we're seen as just one group. We're splitting for efficiency, each with its own manager.

**Naming requirements are:**

- A group of three (bonus points if it's expandable, but not required)
- No priority order (e.g. 1, 2, 3 -- 1 is better than 3)
- Has to be professional (but fun is okay!)
- Can't be lame (e.g. the three stooges)

For instance, we can be Team Red, White, and Blue. There is no priority between these names and we can be patriotic. If we wanted to expand, we can add other colors. But it's kinda basic--lame. We can do better, right?

Any thoughts?

*P.S. If this belongs in another Stack Exchange site, please move it!*

Comment: I have to ask... Three teams working one backlog? Is there focus on this backlog or subsections. IE team A works public services, team B works internal services, team C runs handles infrastructure? (With three teams in one pot unless you have someone above the team passing on marching orders, or each team specializes this could lead to two teams bumping heads)

Comment: We named ours after various beaches. Frankly I liked it better when we were A, B, C, etc.

Comment: Rock, Paper, Scissors?  Sex, Drugs, Rock'n'Roll (maybe not).

Comment: Red, Green Blue; North, East, West;Amazon, Nile Danube;Hawk, Falcon, Eagle; Happy, Grumpy, Sleepy;Stegasaur, Triceratops, Pteranodon ... need I go on?

Comment: Major cities in your country?  Don't use anything in state, but "Team Chicago,"  "Team Dallas,"  "Team Atlanta" are all good.  Pick the right cities, and each team can have a theme song.

Comment: Why do these teams need a name at all? If you're hoping to appeal to some kind of team spirit or something within the people on those teams then your best bet is to step back and let them sort it out organically.

Comment: @RualStorge Honestly, all three teams will work on exactly the same features, maybe not at the same time (SCRUM). We split up for efficiency in standups and to ease group management and meetings. There is also another manager over all three teams.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That's what we're doing. I'm just an engineer on one of the teams and we've been trying to name our teams for the past week (managers too). We all sit near each other and we're pretty close culturally, socially. We want to come up with cool names. The rules I set above is what we all agreed to in our name search (~30 people).

Comment: There are so many obvious solutions .... members of the Cat family: lion, tiger, leopard, panther etc

Answer (score 8):

Why not let your teams choose them? Either let everyone propose and vote on a theme, or let each team vote internally on its own team name.

Give them rules you've just given us, let everyone vote, highest voted name or naming scheme wins. Obviously management can veto anything that's ridiculously inappropriate.

Comment: When my teams were given the opportunity to decide their own names the most popular (but vetoed) result was ["Who", "What" and "Idunno"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who's_on_First%3F).

Comment: I recall a story I once heard about a set of shift workers. They were able to name their shifts. The first shift was "A", the second "B", and the third was "Jerry's Kids."

Comment: We *are* doing this. We're looking for ideas on how to name our teams. I am an engineer on one of the teams and we've been trying for a week now to find cool names for ourselves! That's where I was hoping you guys could help out. We all decided the rules above.

Comment: I think that if you're looking for *methodologies* on how to choose your names it's ok; if you're looking for suggestions the question probably risks getting closed as a poll-style question, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Where I work, teams can decide their names as long as it isn't offensive. I like this idea, since this way the names have no significant meaning (no priority etc.). Also, I suggest you tell them to find a "big team" name, so that it is easier to talk about the three teams together if necessary.